# How to integrate instantpay in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

One of my client want a functionality that recharge online through this third party [https://www.instantpay.in], I do not have any idea about this, how to use it or integration in PHP.

If someone have any idea about it please share me.

Comment: _If someone have any idea..._ What might help you more than looking into their documentation/manuals?

Comment: i could not found documen also if you find it then please share me link . thank you

Comment: @B001 so you did downvote for answer and question without any mentions?

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam sounds like a daring claim......where do you know I am the downvioter as there are 2 of them?

Comment: May I know the reason for the downvote?

Comment: @B001 Stackoverflow is for given proper solution not for downvote without any reason.

Comment: @KaushikBhuva you can check my answer, you can fork that library and add additional requests from the doc also. Happy coding.

Comment: Okay, so you mean to say everything i got form here like ( Recharch of mobile , DTH etc).

Comment: @KaushikBhuva Spare me the drivel

Comment: @KaushikBhuva I don't mean to be condescending but generally if you have no code and nothing to show for it, you *will* get downvoted and sometimes even have the question removed. It happened to me a few times, but you learn from it, and you learn to ask better questions. Sometimes when researching to make educated questions you find the solution to the problem, or atleast a partial solution that can be expanded upon here.

Answer (score 1):

Instantpay does not have any official php library but you can use this 3rd party libarary **[instantpay](https://github.com/mukeshhub/instantpay)**

How to use

**Clients**

```
use Instantpay\BusClient;

$ipay = new BusClient(["IPAY_TOKEN"=>"YOUR_TOCKEN_HERE"]);
```

**Cities**

```
$source_list = $ipay->cities->sources();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($source_list);

$destination_list = $ipay->cities->destinations([
            "request"=>[
                "source"=>1492
            ]
]);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($destination_list);
```

For more reference :
https://docs.instantpay.in/